# I may be small but my maker is big and powerful

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> As is you need me on your trips
>
> Left alone you use me on your trips
>
> Rearranged some use me on their trips
>
> Short and thin
>
> I carry a pin

Who am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It could be

> VISA

As,

> VISA is needed to make trips.
>  Rearranged, visa can become AVIS, which is  plural of AVI- which is a kind of self-proclaimed identifying means- which is again, needed for making trips.

Though,

> VISA ( or its representation in the form of a small stamp) is small, it's issuing authority is generally big( a country).

And finally

> you can have a pin on your visa card to get a cash advance and AVIS is a car rental company- Thanks to SteveV

Comment: rot13(lbh pna unir n cva ba lbhe ivfn gb trg n pnfu nqinapr naq NIVF vf n pne eragny pbzcnal.).  I think you have it!!

Comment: Please edit your answer to include @SteveV input because it is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> A credit/debit card?

As is you need me on your trips

> You need them to pay for the trips

Left alone you use me on your trips

> You used them to cvoer expenses on your trip

Rearranged some use me on their trips

> Not sure

Short and thin

> The plastic is small and thin

I carry a pin

> The PIN for the card is stored on it.

Comment: Maybe a more general one: ROT13(NGZ pneq), and rearrange one can be ROT13(ZNG).

Comment: Rearranged is the key here

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a:

> Briefcase?

As is you need me on your trips

> You need them to store your belongings on your trips.

Left alone you use me on your trips

> It's always in use, keeping your stuff together.

Rearranged some use me on their trips

> Not all people are organised, but some tend to organize their briefcases.

Short and thin

> Quite arguably so.

I carry a pin

> Briefcases tend to have a 3 digit PIN.

And as to "I may be small but my maker is big and powerful":

> Briefcases are manufactured in big factories by big brands.

Comment: Welcome to SE @Outman. Rearranged really implies rearranging the word (lettters in it)

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's a:

> backpack, all fits and goes on trips

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling. Please use the spoiler tag (">!") when answering questions and please try to expand on your answer (explain how your answer fits each of the clues). Otherwise, you are likely to be downvoted.